# Issue in triggering my checkbox in order to make it appear in javascript

Tags: javascript

I hope that  am able to explain my problem properly and you do not blame me!
I want to make a terminal with `<pre>` element and a text box  http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2149/ obviuosly this jsfiddledoes not show anything because I could not put the ajax post server side inside it. I have a jquery ajax post and when a user write and press enter in a textbox this ajax triggers then it fetches a value from backend and show the result in a  html element.

The problem is that when the text box reaches to the end of  element it disppears from the scene so in order to make it appear I need to write sth on it then it appears. but I want it to always be available. how can I do that? I also added setfocus and scroll bar! but each time it disappears and I need to trigger it by writing in it. any idea?

Comment: `text box reaches to the end of element` means?.Use some raw data to depict in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I guess `textarea` can stand on your requirement, but you need to restrict the user to some maximum length.

```
<textarea type="text" id="textInput" name="" style="background: #222; color: #fff; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; resize: none;" autofocus></textarea>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2150/